# Windows 8 Application: String not found

Tags: xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I am developing a Windows 8 App using XAML and C#.
I created a resource dictionary for storing localization strings.

While using the " < String > " tag as it is, the compiler recognizes it but says it is not supported.

In my current configuration:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:s="using:System">

    <s:String x:Key="start">Start</s:String>
    <s:String x:Key="pause">Pause</s:String>
    <s:String x:Key="stop">Stop</s:String>

    <s:String x:Key="deleteSelected">Delete Selected</s:String>

    <s:String x:Key="timer">Timer</s:String>
    <s:String x:Key="timers">Timers</s:String>
    <s:String x:Key="stopper">Stopper</s:String>
    <s:String x:Key="stoppers">Stoppers</s:String>
    <s:String x:Key="alarmClock">Alarm Clock</s:String>
    <s:String x:Key="alarmClocks">Alarm Clocks</s:String>

    <s:String x:Key="recordLap">Record Lap</s:String>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

This is the debug output:

```
'TimeLord.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TimeLord.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Users\Gilad Naaman\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\TimeLord\TimeLord\bin\Debug\AppX\TimeLord.exe', Symbols loaded.
'TimeLord.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Runtime.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TimeLord.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\WinMetadata\Windows.UI.Xaml.winmd', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TimeLord.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TimeLord.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\WinMetadata\Windows.ApplicationModel.winmd', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TimeLord.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Collections\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Collections.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TimeLord.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ObjectModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.ObjectModel.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TimeLord.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TimeLord.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\WinMetadata\Windows.Foundation.winmd', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TimeLord.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.UI.Xaml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.UI.Xaml.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TimeLord.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
A first chance exception of type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in TimeLord.exe
WinRT information: The type 'String' was not found. [Line: 13 Position: 44]
An exception of type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in TimeLord.exe but was not handled in user code
WinRT information: The type 'String' was not found. [Line: 13 Position: 44]
Additional information: Unspecified error
'TimeLord.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime\11.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.DLL'
'TimeLord.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TimeLord.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
A first chance exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in TimeLord.exe
'TimeLord.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Diagnostics.Debug\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Diagnostics.Debug.dll'
The program '[4992] TimeLord.exe: Program Trace' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[4992] TimeLord.exe: Managed (v4.0.30319)' has exited with code -1073741189 (0xc000027b).
Activation of the Windows Store app 'f109d0b0-d566-47cd-9551-2969e7b4abab_capbppsrwz44p!App' failed with error 'Windows was unable to communicate with the target application.  This usually indicates that the target application's process aborted. More information may be available in the Debug pane of the Output window (Debug->Windows->Output)'.
```

Comment: Maybe you should have a look at the built in translation system: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh965329.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

     <x:String x:Key="start">Start</x:String>
```

See [this example on the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh986965.aspx)